# css menu left align won't have a width of 100%

Tags: css, navigation, cross-browser, width

Why doesn't my ul li extend all the way to right of the screen? it seems not 100%.. Please HELP In the example provided. The navigation bar does not fully extend across the screen at certain specific resizing it does; the more i extend the browser widow the larger the gap between the last LI child from the UL and the right side of the browser border gets. When you hover you are able to see it. "sign up" item... Please help...

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(182, 182, 182, 1);
}
div.main_container {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("../images/IMG_0060.JPG");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
div.nav_container {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 700px;
  background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, .75);
}
ul.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
ul.nav li {
  background-color: transparent;
  display: table;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  width: 14.285714286%;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.nav li marquee {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: fantasy;
}
ul.nav li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-family: fantasy;
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: lightgray;
  font-weight: bold;
}
ul.nav li:hover {
  background-color: rgba(205, 205, 205, .50);
}
ul.nav li:hover marquee {
  background-color: black;
  color: lightgreen;
}
ul.nav li:hover a {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_container">
  <div class="nav_container">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#">home</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">projects</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">social</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">tutorials</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <marquee scrollamount="2">
          some sliding text
        </marquee>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">login</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">sign up</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply add

```
min-width with percentage like min-width:99.8% and min-width:14.2%
```

or whatever and it will restrict browser to keep minimum of width specified

Comment: Thank you, I'll try that. @Nirpendra

Comment: I still can't figure it out. I get the same results.

Comment: bro can u send screenshot because for my res :1366x768 , i can see full width

Comment: I figure it out.. ! Thanks for the help! :)